# How to make an array inside a loop and then be able to call it after the loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a code here to do the following:
Prompt the user for how many numbers are going to be entered.  We called this value userRequest.
So, userRequest times we do the following:
    read a String. This String will have the form:  a mixture of digits and letters.
    return the integers of the String and the letters separated.

but in the returning code, I scanned the string character by character, so it printed each input separately. But, my question is how can I print the numbers together as one integer and the letters together as on string. (I think it needs arrays, but I couldn't call an array when it inside a loop)

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Program8{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int userRequest;
    int returnNum;

    System.out.print("How many numbers do you wish to enter?  ");
      while (!scan.hasNextInt()){
        System.err.print("Please try again, with digits only: ");
        scan.next();
      }//while
      userRequest = scan.nextInt();
      
      int sortingNum = 1;
      String str;
      char ch;
      str = scan.nextLine();
      for (int i = 0; i < userRequest; i++){
        System.out.print("* Please enter a string #" + sortingNum + ": ");
        str = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("- String #" + sortingNum++ + " = " + str);
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){
          ch = str.charAt(j);
          if ((ch + 0) >= 48 && (ch + 0) <= 57){
            int digit = ((ch + 0) - 48);
            System.out.println(digit);
          }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++){
          if (str.toLowerCase().charAt(k) >= 'a' && str.toLowerCase().charAt(k) <= 'z')
            System.out.println(str.charAt(k));
        }    
      }//for
  
  }//main
}//Program8
```

Comment: for quick solution, you can just try to use `print` instead of `println`

Comment: you can call an array inside a loop, just don't try declaring it inside the loop :P Although an array isn't necessary here. The answer below by Eran is helpful.

Comment: I know that, but it will limit my ability to use them latter. for example, if I wanted to sum all the integers it would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the number: 
Add the logic to multiply a variable by 10 and add the digits extracted.

For the string: 
Add the logic to append the characters to a stringbuilder object.

Code:

```
 int finalNumber = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){
      ch = str.charAt(j);
      if ((ch + 0) >= 48 && (ch + 0) <= 57){
        int digit = ((ch + 0) - 48);
        finalNumber = finalNumber*10 + digit;
        //System.out.println(digit);
      }
    }
    System.out.println(finalNumber);
    System.out.println();
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++){
      if (str.toLowerCase().charAt(k) >= 'a' && str.toLowerCase().charAt(k) <= 'z') {
        //System.out.println(str.charAt(k));
      finalString.append(str.charAt(k));
      }
    }
    System.out.println(finalString.toString());
```

Comment: I just have one question.. why if we didn't initialize the variable finalNumber to 0 we get an error?